# WebSocket закрывается после отправки сообщения

Tags: node.js, websocket

Есть проблема, после отправки данных сокет закрывается, но закрывается он ели отправлять данные так `ws.send(message, {binary: true, mask: true})` , но если отправлять данные просто как строку `ws.send(message)` - то сокет не закрывается. В чем может быть ошибка?

```
webSocketServer.on('connection', function (ws) {
    console.log('->> OnConnect');

    ws.on('message', function(message,flags) {
        console.log('->> OnMessage');

        ws.send(message, {binary: true, mask: true});
    });


    ws.on('close', function () {
        console.log('->> OnClose');
    })

});
```

Comment: Возможно, он закрывается с ошибкой? Я не вижу у вас обработчиков ошибок.

Comment: Ну явных ошибок мне в консоль не выпадает,  я Node юзаю всего пару дней, не подскажите как и в каком месте нужно ловить исключения? Я ещё думаю , может ли быть ошибка в том что я посылаю вместо байтов обычную строку, но посылаю её как байты?

Comment: Помоему лучше делать JSON.parse() и JSON.stringify() если посылаешь объекты PS: ws.send ,а не ws.emit ?

Comment: Мне нужно байты посылать а не Json, c json'ом проблем нету

Comment: а если посылать через ws.emit ,а не через ws.send?

Comment: может это поможет https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client#sending-and-receiving-binary